# COUNT number of NULLs in multiple columns

Tags: postgresql

I want to count the number of occurrences of `NULL` in several columns in a single table. I need the counts per column, not a total count on the entire table. I would very strongly prefer to do so in a single query, to avoid the overhead of the back and forth, simplify my app side code, and avoid multiple table scans.

How can I count the number of rows where each particular column is `NULL`?

#### Ideas so far

- `COUNT` explicit counts things that are not `NULL`, but I could do this to invert `NULL` into not-`NULL` and vice versa to force `COUNT` to do what I want:

  ```
  SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN my_column IS NULL THEN TRUE ELSE NULL END) FROM my_table;
  ```

  but that's really, really ugly, especially since I want to do this on multiple columns in the same query.
- `NULLIF` returns `NULL` when the input is `NULL`, so that isn't helpful.

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)-COUNT(column1) As column1, COUNT(*)-COUNT(column2) As column2 FROM my_table;
```

Maybe this will work for you. Since like you mentioned, `COUNT` only counts non-null values, this should give you the sum of null values you need.

Comment: I briefly mentioned that I want to do this on multiple columns in the same query. I'll revise the question to emphasize that more. Thank you! And sorry I wasn't more clear.

Comment: @jpmc26 I see - Does the edit seem more appropriate?

Comment: I seem to have more clarifying to do. I need the counts on individual columns (so number of `NULL`s in columnA and number of `NULL`s in columnB). Sorry again. And I do appreciate the help.